# How to open a form view (wizard) after button click in odoo 13 in Sales

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-13

i have created a button "**+Add Products**" below order lines using **inheritance** and **xpath** in ***sale.order*** in Odoo 13.0 Sales Module, my aim is that when i click "+Add Products" button, Just open a wizard (like customized form view, where i can fill products details) and also create below **Add**  button in wizard.

```
quotation_product.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']" 
            position="before">
                    <button name="my_button" string=" + Add Products" type="object" class="btn 
                btn-info btn- lg"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>

quotation_product.py

from odoo import api, fields, models, api

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"
    _name = "sale.order"

    def my_button(self, context=None):
        print("ghghhhghghghghg")

    return True
```

Comment: community please help me, where i made mistake, i begineer in odoo development..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr op,

On your button, you can return your view like this,
So pass the `object` and your module `view`.In that, your `view` added the `button` on footer and with same added the logic on that `footer_button` to perform in your customized way.

```
def my_button(self):
    return {
        'name': "Your String",
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'object',
        'view_id': self.env.ref('module.view_id').id,
        'target': 'new'
    }
```

And In your `py` file if you want to inherit the odoo `defaul_object` like `sale.order` then no need to use the `_name`.

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"
```

You can also refer and find the official odoo13 documentation.

Thanks